# How should I write a query to be able to search for input text in SQL database?

Tags: android, listview

I have this function which is not working

```
 public Cursor getSomeData(String text){



    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME},
            PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%" + text + "%"},
            null, null, null);
}
```

I want to search by inputText from a editText , this is what I have in main Activity :

```
 searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = searchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            customAdapter1 = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this , databaseHelper.getSomeData(text));
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter1);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

This give a crash to my app , when I try to write something in my editText

EDIT :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:116)
            at com.example.cosmin.database.CustomCursorAdapter.<init>(CustomCursorAdapter.java:24)
            at com.example.cosmin.database.MyActivity$2.afterTextChanged(MyActivity.java:117)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7346)
            at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9017)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:674)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:437)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2:

Now I receive another error which crash my app :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>   And this error lead me to this code :

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));


}
```

If I change the 1 from getColumnName with 0 , everything from my listview will change to numbers from 0 to how many items I have in list , and if I try to searh by input name , my listview will upgrade like I want , but with numbers !!

What can I do for this error "Index out of bounds " ?
EDIT 3:

[First one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjuab.png)

[And second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQ9c.png)

Comment: Guys, ALWAYS post logcats, errors, we can not guess your problems - how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Please post your error log from logcat.

Comment: I just edited my post , thank you for your interest !

Comment: It seems that your database don't find the _id column. Can you log the complete SQL statement?

Comment: Also, please provide a screenshot of your database structure

Comment: I just edited my post !

Comment: Seems like you only HAVE one column with your IDs, that's why I said - **provide a screenshot of your database please**

Comment: My problem now , is not comming from my database , because is working if I give 0 like parameter to cursor.getColumnName(0) , I get out of bounds exception

Comment: Dude, indexOutOfBounds is thrown if you are trying to access data that just is not there. You can not access array[1] which only has 1 field, which is at array[0]. If your database only contains (autoincremented) IDs, you only have **one** field to read from. Therefore `getColumnName(0)` works, and everything else does not. So, if you would finally share a screenshot of your database structure, we could tackle the root of this problem.

Comment: Ok man , I get it , I just uploaded my photos , and thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solved my problem , it was a missing thing from my query !!

Here is my code:

```
public Cursor getSomeData(String text){



    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID,PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME},   //Here was my issue!
            PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%" + text + "%"},
            null, null, null);
}
```